# Writing to a file in C while reading from it in python

Tags: python, c, io, mutex

I am working with an Altera DE1-SoC board where I am reading data from a sensor using a C program. The data is being read continually, in a while loop and written to a text file. I want to read this data using a python program and display the data.

The problem is that I am not sure how to avoid collision during the read/write from the file as these need to happen simultaneously. I was thinking of creating a mutex, but I am not sure how to implement it so the two different program languages can work with it.

Is there a simple way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you writing to a file?  Seems much cleaner to write the data to a pipe.

Comment: @WilliamPursell It seemed more simple to me. Can you explain a bit how I would read and write to a fifo or a pipe? It still confuses me because I am using two different program languages.

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/1/mkfifo might give you a good starting point

Comment: If you were on a hosted system, you could probably just use a named pipe: `mkfifo /tmp/fifo; cmd1 > /tmp/fifo & cmd2 < /tmp/fifo` . Doesn't matter if cmd1 is C or python or java or ada.  Language is irrelevant.

Comment: @william: you don't even need a shell. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mkfifo.3.html

Answer (score 1):

You could load a C library into Python using `cdll.LoadLibrary` and call a function to get the status of the C mutex. Then in Python if the C mutex is locking then don't read, and if it is unlocked then it can read.

Comment: would it work on embedded linux? since those programs are used on the board which is running a linux kernel.

Comment: As long as the Python version supported `cdll.LoadLibrary` it would work.

Answer (score 1):

Operating system will take care of this as long as you can open that file twice (one for read and one for write). Just remember to flush from C code to make sure your data are actually written to disk, instead of being kept in cache in memory.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what do you mean by conflict. I assume that it is a line broken in half, because one process started writing and the other interrupted it and started reading.

You can use `pyinotify (0.9.6)` package to watch your log file of interest for modification events. Assuming that the only modification is the append operation you could use a code like this:

```
import pyinotify
import functools

wm = pyinotify.WatchManager()
notifier = pyinotify.Notifier(wm, default_proc_fun=lambda _e: _e)
wm.add_watch('/home/user/somefile', pyinotify.IN_MODIFY)

def my_read_routine(notifier, fd):
    while True:
        content = fd.readline()
        if not content:
            break
        print(content, end = '')

read_callback = functools.partial(my_read_routine, fd=open('somefile', 'r'))

notifier.loop(callback=read_callback)
```

This cryptic lambda in `default_proc_fun` is just a dummy replacement used to remove default processing routine, which prints events to stdout. Remove it from arguments list to see what I mean.